# addressables unity unknown async error

Tags: unity, assets

```
public AssetLabelReference imgs;
List<IResourceLocation> myImgs = new List<IResourceLocation>();
[SerializeField]List<Texture2D> loadedImages = new List<Texture2D>();
private void Start()
{
    Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync(imgs.labelString).Completed += imgReady;
}
void imgReady(AsyncOperationHandle<IList<IResourceLocation>> op)
{
    myImgs = new List<IResourceLocation>(op.Result);
    insta();
}
 void insta()
{
    Addressables.LoadAssetsAsync<Texture2D>(myImgs, cb);
}
void cb(Texture2D s)
{
    loadedImages.Add(s);
}
```

I get the locations of the images but not the asset themselves
I get an error of

> Exception encountered in operation Resource(Man.png): Unknown error in AsyncOperation
>   UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.Util.DelayedActionManager:LateUpdate() (at